# React Flow - pan the flow on drag a node with drag handle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-flow

It seems that React Flow won't allow you to pan the flow on drag a node, and that makes sense.

I thought it can be possible to bypass this restriction if I used [Drag Handle](https://reactflow.dev/examples/nodes/drag-handle) but it doesn't!

[image: drag handle example by react-flow]

In the example provided by React Flow about using Drag Handle, you can pan the flow only on drag the dotted background.

I want to be able to pan the flow on drag the node from anywhere but the drag handle.

I tried the `pan` class name but it doesn't work since the node is draggable.